# Counting strategies Exam Question

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many different ways can people finish in

i) a $4$ person race, ii) a $6$ person race,  iii) a $10$ person race

What I did:
$4^4 = 256$

$6^6 = 46,656$

$10^{10}$

as there are $4$ people and therefore 4th place 3rd place 2nd place and 1st place so $4$ to the power of $4$.

I don't know where I went wrong and is there a formulae for working out these type of questions?

Thank You and Help is Appreciated

Comment: Try your approach on a $2$ person race.  Do you believe that there are $2^2=4$ ways for them to finish?

Comment: O yes true.....

Comment: Research permutations....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because there are $4$  ways to choose the first person and $4$ ways to choose the second person doesn't mean there are $16$ ways to choose both; some combinations such as $AAAA$ are't allowed (but are still counted).

Instead, try looking at the [factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Comment: O yes I understand now how if someone gets first they can't get second so the chance decreases by 1 so I have to use the factorial function. Thank You! c:

Comment: Yup! That's exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

Approach with multiplication principle.

- Pick who the person who finishes first is
- Pick who the person who finishes *second* is.  (*Note that the person who finishes first will not also finish second and so they should not be considered eligible anymore for any of the later positions*)
- Pick who the person who finishes third is.  (*Similarly, neither the person who finishes first nor the person who finishes second are able to also finish third, so there are two fewer people available to choose from here*)
- $\vdots$

Multiplying the number of options available for each step gives the total.  Note that multiplication principle works so long as the *number* of options available at each step doesn't depend on the choices made in previous steps, but what those specific options *are* can indeed change based on previously made choices, such as here.

Comment: O yes so 4 times 3 times 2 times 1